# How to get option for select tag in forms.py from my model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Please help me to solve this problem! I have form for job application and I have this in my 
models.py:

```
class Vacancy(models.Model):
vacancy_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
vacancy_description = models.TextField()
data = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
contact_person = models.CharField(max_length=50)
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
mail = models.EmailField();

def __str__(self):
    return self.vacancy_title
```

A user must choose one of the vacancies

```
        <select name="job_field" id="job_field">
            {% for vacancy in vacancies %}
            <option value="">{{ vacancy.vacancy_title }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
```

Here is the forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Vacancy

CHOICES = (Vacancy.objects.all().values_list('vacancy_title', flat=True))


class ApplicantForm(forms.Form):
   name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
   surname = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
   email = forms.EmailField()
   selected_position = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
```

And the views.py:

```
def send_resume(request):

vacancies = Vacancy.objects.all();

if request.method == 'POST':

    form = ApplicantForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['applicant_name']
        surname = form.cleaned_data['applicant_surname']
        passport_number = form.cleaned_data['passport_number']
        from_mail = form.cleaned_data['mail']
        position = form.cleaned_data['position']

    else:
        form = ApplicantForm()

context = {'vacancies': vacancies}
return render(request, 'interactive/send_resume.html', context)
```

Now in the forms.py I cannot connect vacancy_title to the choice of the select group(Choice Field). How to do it?

Comment: Well you can, but I wonder why you write the template explcitly, and not use a `Form` here?

Comment: Please add your forms.py and your views function

Comment: As I couldn't manage connecting models field to the choice field in forms.py i just deleted it wrote that one for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField).

```
selected_position = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Vacancy.objects.all(), empty_label='(Nothing)')
```

It's more generic way

Answer (score 1):

Use  `django-model-utils` module.  Your model code can look as below.

```
from model_utils import Choices

VACANCY_CHOICE = Choices(
          ('MANAGER', 'MANAGER', _('Development Manager')),
          ('SALES', 'SALES', _('Sales VP')),
)

class Vacancy(models.Model):
    vacancy_title = models.CharField(choices=VACANCY_CHOICE, default=VACANCY_CHOICE.MANAGER,max_length=100)
```

Try to use `{{form}}` in your template.

Comment: Thank you bro! But the Choices must retrieved from my models.py -> Vacancy and the vacancy_title of the all the objects should the option of the select.